# C calculate wrong number in multiplication

Tags: c, math, multiplication

i am simply trying to multiply 2 numbers and store them on an unsigned long long variable.
however the result seems to be wrong and i also made sure that the result does not cause any overflow to happen. why is it calculating the wrong number?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long num = 0;
    
    num = 260000000 * 25;
    printf("num = %llu\n", num);
    
    num = 0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++){
        num += 260000000;
    }
    printf("num = %llu\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Result:
num = 18446744071619617024
num = 6500000000
```

notice in the first example i'm multiplying directly and it produces the wrong number while the second example by looping them manually gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`260000000 * 25` is an `int` multiplication. If you want an `unsigned long long` value then you need to use the `ULL` (or `ull`) suffix:

```
    num = 260000000ULL * 25;
```

Or you write it like this:

```
    unsigned long long num = 260000000;
    num *= 25;
```

Or use a cast:

```
    num = (unsigned long long) 260000000 * 25;
```

Comment: thanks @Allan Wind and @ DavidGrayson, it works now

Comment: @aregularcoder If you read the manual you'll see the prescribed way for an OP to "accept" an answer is to "accept" the answer. Written thanks are nice, but the green checkmark against a question is significant to others.